# How to upload photo to image hosting website programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to upload photo programmatically from phone to any photo hosting website(any suggestion for a photo hosting site?)? I need to get the URL only for the uploaded photo to use it on my app. How do you do that?

Comment: using http - n java Apache Http Components is a tool, but the exact how depends on website, their process and rules. You should use google to find a suitable site and come back here with a more specif c question after considering Terms and conditions

Comment: https://api.imgur.com/ next stop is finding a HTTP lib and test code to work with on IOS

Comment: Hi @tgkprog, how specific you want my question? My only problem is how I can upload a photo to any free image hosting site(if any) programmatically and pull its URL to use it on my app? Thanks for api.imgur.com , i'll check it. P.S.-I'm doing this for learning purposes only.

Comment: read the [FAQ] your question is open, i anyway tried to help you - gave u a sample to go after, and looks like someone has given u a sample too - basically a google search!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service that offer some `API` like *imgur*.

You can **download the library** and **see a snippet of code** to implement the upload, [here on the imgur github page](https://github.com/geoffmacd/ImgurSession).